# Web page detect network connect lost to provide refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Couldn't find this particular question posted, but am having some difficulties with a "Dashboard" style 1-page web page thing I'm building. It performs repetitive AJAX calls to some scripts and displays stats.

What is happening is if the computer loses network connectivity (even briefly - like with wifi dropping out or VPN disconnecting), there's no indication that this happens and the page's AJAX calls stop. This isn't apparent to the user, so they think they're looking at current stats when really it stopped "refreshing" when the network dropped out.

How I came across this is Chrome's console showing the entries below:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Is there a way to possibly "test" or detect when this occurs so I can refresh the page, or "restart" my AJAX calls?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status

Comment: Cool, thanks for those links! Had no idea that was built in to the browsers now! Got me to https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/06/navigator-onLine-in-Chrome-Dev-channel?hl=en which showed me two event listeners to use.